# Dual Video Cards (Primary, Secondary with HDMI) to Provide HDMI Out Signal to TV

Tags: graphics-card, hdmi, tv

My computer is currently running Windows 7 Professional x64 and the computer has an nVidia GTX 260 graphics card with dual DVI output (only), which is hooked up to my dual monitors.

I just recently bought a television has supports HDMI in and would like to watch movies that currently reside on my hard drive.

Would it be possible to have both [this card](http://www.tigerdirect.ca/applications/searchtools/item-details.asp?EdpNo=5677177&csid=ITD&body=REBATES) and my GTX 260 installed at the same time (in non-SLI obviously) and switch between them for the purposes of watching movies on my TV?
If so, is this something I have to set up within Windows, or is this something I have to setup through the BIOS (set the default PCI bus to have a primary/secondary output and switch between them?).
If not, what are some of the ways to get a high definition signal from my computer, which only supports DVI out, to my TV? Am I out of luck?

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention. I do not have a speaker system (only headphones) so I need to send audio as well as video. Is a simple HDMI->DVI converter enough to do this? I thought DVI does not transport audio as well.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

DVI-D and HDMI have the same video signaling. Get yourself a [cheap adapter](http://www.tigerdirect.ca/applications/SearchTools/search.asp?keywords=dvi+hdmi+adapter) and use that.

Comment: I've updated my original question. I need to send audio as well. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: There are DVI+audio-to-HDMI adapters as well, but they're more expensive and require digital audio.